# Как сделать GRANT для всех таблиц базы данных?

Tags: sql-server

База данных - Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: опишите свою задачу точнее, может быть вам поможет данная ссылка https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/getting-started-with-database-engine-permissions

Comment: Возможно, под вашу задачу лучше подойдёт [db_datareader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)